# Evaluate all relative extreme and saddle points of the function, f(x,y)=e^-x * sin y

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Evaluate all relative extreme and saddle points of the function,

f(x,y)={e}^x * sin y[image]

i have tried but i cannot finish it and i did not know if it was correct.

Comment: Consider showing what you have tried in the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The function is $f(x,y)=e^{-x\sin y}.$

To compute the extreme values of the given function we put

$f_{x}=-\sin y. e^{-x\sin y}=0$$\Rightarrow$$\sin y=0$ or $y=n\pi,$ where $n\in\mathbb{Z},$
 because $e^{-x\sin y}$ can not be zero.

and $f_{y}=-x\cos y.e^{-x\sin y}=0$$\Rightarrow$$x\cos y=0$$\Rightarrow$$x=0$ or $y=(2n+1)\frac{\pi}{2}$ where $n\in\mathbb{Z},$

Hence the if we consider all points of the form $\bigg(0,(2n+1)\frac{\pi}{2}\bigg)$ then $f_y=0$ but $f_x\neq0$ and if we consider all points of the form $(0,n\pi)$ then $f_x=0$ but $f_y\neq0.$

Hence there exists no critical points of the given function.

Therefore, no relative extrema or saddle points exists for the given function.